# Combine two vectors into a dataframe with bind_rows and add identifier in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(5,6,7,8,9)
```

I want to combine them in a data frame and add an identifier like this:

```
   value ID
1      1  a
2      2  a
3      3  a
4      4  a
5      5  a
6      5  b
7      6  b
8      7  b
9      8  b
10     9  b
```

I tried to use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(list(a,b), .id = "ID")
```

However, it provides an error:

> Error in `bind_rows()`:
> ! Argument 1 must have names.

Any idea what is going wrong? What am I missing to bind these rows into a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(5,6,7,8,9)

df <- tibble(a,b) %>% 
       pivot_longer(everything(),
                    names_to='ID',
                    values_to='value') %>% 
       arrange(ID,value)
```

About your code, `bind_rows` needs named arguments. `bind_rows(list(a=a,b=b), .id = "ID")` works for me (notice I just added `a=a` and `b=b` inside the list call) but it does the same as `tibble(a,b)`, which I find easier to read, I don't know about computational timing between those two though.